# Odoo: _get_state() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given) in xml view

Tags: python, odoo

Here is mycode. I want to get id_employee of current record before define its model class:

```
def _get_state(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    idemployee = ""
    for adv in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
        id_employee = adv.id_employee
        if id_employee is None:
            idemployee = _default_employee(self, cr, uid, context=None)
        else:
            idemployee = id_employee

    sql = " SELECT C.id AS id, C.sequence, C.name \
                   FROM wf_group_member A \
           LEFT JOIN wf_group B ON B.id = A.group_id \
           LEFT JOIN wf_process BB ON BB.id = B.process_id \
           LEFT JOIN wf_state C ON C.group_id = B.id \
           LEFT JOIN hr_employee D ON D.id = A.member_id \
           WHERE LOWER(code) = 'ca' AND member_id = %s ORDER BY sequence "
    res = []
    cr.execute(sql, [(idemployee)])
    ardata = cr.fetchall()
    for data in ardata:
        res.append((data[1], data[2]))
    return res
```

and this is my model class that I put it after _get_state function

```
class cashadvance(osv.osv):
    _name = 'ga.cashadvance'
    _columns = {
        'id_user'                   : fields.many2one('res.users', string='User', required=True, readonly=True),
        'state'                     : fields.selection(_get_state, 'Status', readonly=True),
        'id_employee'               : fields.many2one('hr.employee', string='Employee', required=True, readonly=True),
    }
```

When I call _get_state function, it raised error :

```
Error details:
global name 'ids' is not defined
None" while parsing /opt/custom-addons/comben/views/cashadvance_view.xml:4, near
<record id="cashadvance_list" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">cashadvance_list</field>
            <field name="model">ga.cashadvance</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Cashadvance List">
                    <field name="id_employee"/>
                    <field name="category_id"/>
                    <field name="est_date_from" string="Est Date From"/>
                    <field name="est_date_to" string="Est Date To"/>
                    <field name="description"/>
                    <field name="state"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </record>
```

can somebady help me please, thanks

Comment: what's this supposed to do `idemployee = _default_employee(self, cr, uid, context=None)`, specifically what's `_default_employee`?

Comment: _default_employee is a function to call employee_id in hr_employee by uid, it will return employee_id, and it no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`_get_state` has to be part of the class for you to use it not outside the class, the self you're passing in there is not seen as the python `self` i.e the current instance, it's seen as a normal argument of the function.

Python isn't passing in self for you, let me deviate a little and reproduce the error you're getting. look at this code

```
def func(self,cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    pass

class func_test:
    def __init__(self):
        func(1, 1, 1, context=1)

a = func_test()
```

This is the Error raised (make sure you run this with python2)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    a = func_test()
  File "script.py", line 6, in __init__
    func(1, 1, 1, context=1)
TypeError: func() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given)
```

python is actually correct even though it's misleading, the function expects at least four arguments because context is a keyword argument and has been filled in at the time of the function definition, but it's still missing one parameter, because the function is outside a class so the first argument which is usually called `self` is taken as a normal parameter (since it's a function) not a method (function in a class). so starting from left to right `self`, `cr`, `uid` would be filled in as `1` `1` `1` leaving `ids` and at this point python would cry out for help because no value was found for that argument, if we move that function into the class and call it with `self.func`, the current instance automatically gets passed for us.

```
class func_test:
    def func(self,cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        self.func(1, 1, 1, context=1)

a = func_test()
```

Of course you could still have `func(self, 1, 1, 1, context=1)` but that would be defeating the purpose of methods

But note that python3 is smarter and handles this scenario better than python2, this is a python3 traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    a = func_test()
  File "script.py", line 6, in __init__
    func(1, 1, 1, context=1)
TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ids'
```

It plainly tells us that no value was provided for `ids` in the function call

so going back to Odoo your code should look like this

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class cashadvance(osv.osv):
    _name='comben.cashadvance'

    def _get_state(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        idemployee = ""

        ids = self.search(cr, uid, [], context=context) # you probably want to search for all the records
        for adv in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            id_employee = adv.id_employee
            if id_employee is None:
                idemployee = self._default_employee(cr, uid, ids, context=None) # might raise singleton error if more than one record is returned
            else:
                idemployee = id_employee.id

        sql = " SELECT C.id AS id, C.sequence, C.name \
                   FROM wf_group_member A \
           LEFT JOIN wf_group B ON B.id = A.group_id \
           LEFT JOIN wf_process BB ON BB.id = B.process_id \
           LEFT JOIN wf_state C ON C.group_id = B.id \
           LEFT JOIN hr_employee D ON D.id = A.member_id \
           WHERE LOWER(code) = 'ca' AND member_id = %s ORDER BY sequence "
        res = []
        cr.execute(sql, [(idemployee)])
        ardata = cr.fetchall()
        for data in ardata:
            res.append((data[1], data[2]))

       return res 

    _columns = {
        'id_user': fields.many2one('res.users', string='User', required=True, readonly=True),
        'state': fields.selection(_get_state, string='Status', readonly=True),
        'id_employee': fields.many2one('hr.employee', string='Employee', required=True, readonly=True),
    }
```

and also move `_default_employee` into the class body, so you can call it like this

```
self._default_employee(cr, uid, context=None) # python implicitly passes self for you
```

xml view

```
<record id="cashadvance_list" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">cashadvance list</field>
  <field name="model">comben.cashadvance</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="Cashadvance List">
      <field name="id_employee"/>
      <field name="id_user"/>
      <field name="state"/>
    </tree>
  </field>
</record>
```

Comment: I followed your code, and raised error : "global name 'ids' is not defined".
it seems from the part of : for adv in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context):
need more help please

Comment: oops sorry, I 've add ids in _get_state argument, but then raised error :

ParseError: "Invalid view definition

Error details:
get_state() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given)
None" while parsing /opt/custom-addons/comben/views/cashadvance_view.xml:4, near,

still the same error, I'm really confused of that

Comment: Did you follow my latest code....and also please paste this xml that's raising errors

Comment: Yes I did, this is the xml:
ParseError:Invalid view definition
Error details:
get_state() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given)
None" while parsing /opt/custom-addons/comben/views/cashadvance_view.xml:4, near
<record id="cashadvance_list" model="ir.ui.view">
   <field name="name">cashadvance_list</field>
   <field name="model">comben.cashadvance</field>
   <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <tree string="Cashadvance List">
     <field name="id_user"/>
                                        <field name="id_employee"/>
     <field name="state"/>
    </tree>
   </field>
  </record>

Comment: I described it all in comment bellow

Comment: i've posted another edit that should work for you i also included some comments in the code, the problem is that `ids` isn't available when you're setting the default value of an object, ids is usually gotten from the form..it's the `[id]` of the current record/records in the form view...i also don't understand why you have a selection field and you made it readonly...even the other fields. this means that the user won't be able to interact the form or change the values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121918/discussion-between-yogakumboro-and-danidee).

Comment: one more question please, in **"else: id_employee"** raised error : **can't adapt type 'hr.employee'**, but when I changed variable id_employee with particular id employee such as: **else: 1348** the error was missing, thanks

Comment: yeah that should be `id_employee = id_employee.id`...the id of the record not the recordset itself.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you want this :

```
def _get_state(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        current_record=self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
        idemployee = current_record[0].id_employee

    sql = " SELECT C.id AS id, C.sequence, C.name \
                   FROM wf_group_member A \
           LEFT JOIN wf_group B ON B.id = A.group_id \
           LEFT JOIN wf_process BB ON BB.id = B.process_id \
           LEFT JOIN wf_state C ON C.group_id = B.id \
           LEFT JOIN hr_employee D ON D.id = A.member_id \
           WHERE LOWER(code) = 'ca' AND member_id = %s ORDER BY sequence "
    res = []
    cr.execute(sql, [(idemployee)])
    ardata = cr.fetchall()
    for data in ardata:
        res.append((data[1], data[2]))
    return res
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I need to get the field value before the column because I want to use that field value as parameter cr.execure in get_state function for state field selection

Comment: I followed your code, and raise error in xml : 

ParseError: "Invalid view definition

Error details:
global name 'ids' is not defined

Comment: and when I put ids inside get_state, def get_state(self, cr, uid, context=None):
it raised error : get_state() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given) in xml view