# Understanding "takes at least X arguments (X given)" error in Odoo

Tags: python, python-2.7, arguments, odoo-8, odoo

I have the following code in a method of the `stock.picking` model:

```
...
for line in picking.move_lines:
    if line.procurement_id and line.procurement_id.sale_line_id:
        sale_line = line.procurement_id.sale_line_id
        _logger.info(sale_line)
        cur = sale_line.order_id.pricelist_id.currency_id
        price = sale_line._calc_line_base_price()
        qty = sale_line._calc_line_quantity()
        ...
```

I am checking with the logger that `sale_line` variable is a `sale.order.line` object -I am getting *sale.order.line(14,)*-, so I cannot understand why I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: _calc_line_base_price() takes at least 4 arguments (4
>   given)

If I call that method with old API format, it works, but how to call it with new API format?

This answer explains the problem very well, but I think it is not my case as the method I am calling is inside the class of `sale.order.line`:

[Odoo: _get_state() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given) in xml view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094524/odoo-get-state-takes-at-least-4-arguments-4-given-in-xml-view)

Can anyone explain me this? By the way, I am working with version 8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: function() takes at least n arguments (n given)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30473468/error-function-takes-at-least-n-arguments-n-given)

Comment: (while the specific function called is different, the cause and the explanation is exactly the same.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While calling an old style method within a new style method, Odoo tries to wrap the parameters correctly. Problem here is the method `_calc_line_base_price` because it can't be wrapped automatically.

```py
def _calc_line_base_price(self, cr, uid, line, context=None):
```

The parameter `line` is unsual for this type of methods (call on one instance, new api would be `@api.multi` with a `self.ensure_one()`). So you need to call it like a "static" odoo class method:

```py
price = self.env['sale.order.line']._calc_line_base_price(sale_line)
```